# Man page for file permission numbers

Tags: permissions, man, chmod

## Is there a man page for the file permission numbers?

I'm specifically talking about

```
r = 4
w = 2
x = 1
```

I can never remember them and I have to google it every time I need to set permissions besides 755. I don't think I'm alone, either, since there's [even a site that calculates the number for you](http://permissions-calculator.org/).

I just realized the man page for `chmod` doesn't have any description of the numbers and I can't figure out what other page would have them. I guess an `info` page would work as well, since apparently it comes pre-installed (I have arch; I'd have thought I'd have had to install that one myself--apparently not). It would be a lot easier for me if I could just refer to an 'on-line' man page (I use 'on-line' in the sense used in `man man`).

Comment: I am having trouble [finding](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) a [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chmod&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) page [that](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?chmod+1+NetBSD-current) doesn't [list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m5s/index.html) the mode bits in it. The GNU man page it sounds like you'd have certainly does: "The second digit selects permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4), write (2), and execute (1)". Are you sure it's not there?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yeah, I should have read more carefully. I was looking for a table. Terrible laziness on my part all day today.

Comment: I remember it in terms of postion, rwx, and convert from binary.  So "r" is 100, "w" is 010, "x" is 001.  In binary that means r=4, w=2, x=1.  When you see enough `ls -l` output that "rwx" order eventually gets stuck in your mind :-)

Comment: @StephenHarris I very much expected this: someone to answer the question and then give me a helpful mnemonic so that I don't even need to look it up anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Why on Earth do people use numbers to set file permissions?  "chmod [ugo][+-][rwx] works perfectly well for most cases (and there are options for less common ones - read the man page), and is almost impossible to forget.

Comment: Because that's how it was done in the 1970s when Unix was first developed, and by now there's lots and lots of literature and scripts using the old scheme. As a result, new users will sooner or later need to at least understand the old scheme... and it's not such a huge stretch to start using it once you understand it. Which one would you rather type, if you needed to do it several times: `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx` or `755`?

Comment: @jamesqf, because it's shorter to write `640` (or even `0640`) than to write `u=rw,g=r,o=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man chmod` is likely to give you the command line tool.  This may include some text that is easy to miss

> The second digit selects permissions for the user who owns the  file:  read (4),  write  (2),  and  execute  (1)

If you do `man 2 chmod` then you get the system call that actually does the work.  This is harder to read, but does include the magic numbers:

```
   S_IRUSR  (00400)  read by owner
   S_IWUSR  (00200)  write by owner
   S_IXUSR  (00100)  execute/search  by owner ("search" applies for direc-
                     tories, and means that entries within  the  directory
                     can be accessed)
   S_IRGRP  (00040)  read by group
   S_IWGRP  (00020)  write by group
   S_IXGRP  (00010)  execute/search by group
   S_IROTH  (00004)  read by others
   S_IWOTH  (00002)  write by others
   S_IXOTH  (00001)  execute/search by others
```

It also provides some other magic values:

```
   S_ISUID  (04000)  set-user-ID  (set  process  effective  user   ID   on
                     execve(2))

   S_ISGID  (02000)  set-group-ID  (set  process  effective  group  ID  on
                     execve(2);  mandatory  locking,   as   described   in
                     fcntl(2);  take a new file's group from parent direc-
                     tory, as described in chown(2) and mkdir(2))

   S_ISVTX  (01000)  sticky bit (restricted deletion flag, as described in
                     unlink(2))
```

Comment: Any idea what the `S_I` prefix stands for?

Comment: @undercat I always guessed it was "stat" "inode"... but that's just a guess and probably totally wrong :-)